# Access Update Query First 5 digits, but last number goes up one

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using Access Update Query to change a column to the first 5 digits, I got that part.  But I ALSO need the last digit to go up one.  So if its 12345 I need it to be 12346.

This is what I have so far:

```
Left([Num],5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CLng(Left([Num], 5)) + 1
```

The `CLng` is only necessary if the original column isn't already a number field.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!